# NetBeans 7.0 command line arguments

Tags: c, netbeans

Can someone tell me how to add arguments to the commandline in NetBeans 7.0 I see in earlier versions one would go file - project properties - run and simply add them, but in 7.0 it is setup differently. 
This is specifically for C projects.
Any help?
Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 7):

You need to enclose each additional argument in quotation marks, and add them to the end of the Run Command line. By default, mine is set up to take one arg: "${OUTPUT_PATH}"

I wanted the program to also take a port number as a string, so I changed this line to: "${OUTPUT_PATH}" "6969"

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked, the project properties are in exactly the same place as in previous versions.

[image: Project Properties Dialog]

Comment: mine does not look like that. I cannot upload screenshots but I am running 7.0 on Linux. It does not look the same.

Comment: The code works if I run it from the command line but I would like to be able to run it straight off the IDE. This is becoming such a pain! I am having all the trouble in the world with xCode netbeans aaand eclipse trying to pass arguments to the command line in C. In Java I have had zero problems.

Answer (score 0):

Go to NetBeans "**File**" menu

Click "**Project Properties**"

Click "**Run**" on left hand side categories list

On "**Run Command**" at Right hand side add your arguments separated by ""

e.g. "${OUTPUT_PATH}" "ABC.txt" "7896" "ASDF"